# How to Vlookup multiple values and return results in a column? I tried with an array formula but it results in rendering the Excel too slow

Tags: excel, if-statement

The work gets done using the below formula, however it makes the Excel too slow. Is there a similar formula I could use?

I have a long list of entries structured in the following way (Month, content, account, amount). I need to display all entries that have the same account and the occur in the same months together in a table were also content and amount are displayed. Therefore, I need that each time Month & Account are the same, the entire rows of these elements are listed in a separate table.

`=IFERROR(INDEX('Account Payable 19-20'!B:B,SMALL(IF('Account Payable 19-20'!$G:$G=($C$2&$B$4),ROW('Account Payable 19-20'!B:B)-MIN(ROW('Account Payable 19-20'!B:B))+1),ROWS($M$6:N7))),"")`

`=IFERROR(INDEX('Account Payable 19-20'!C:C,SMALL(IF('Account Payable 19-20'!$G:$G=($C$2&$B$4),ROW('Account Payable 19-20'!C:C)-MIN(ROW('Account Payable 19-20'!C:C))+1),ROWS($M$6:N7))),"")`

`=IFERROR(INDEX('Account Payable 19-20'!D:D,SMALL(IF('Account Payable 19-20'!$G:$G=($C$2&$B$4),ROW('Account Payable 19-20'!D:D)-MIN(ROW('Account Payable 19-20'!D:D))+1),ROWS($M$6:N7))),"")`

Comment: From the description of your issue.. why not just use a pivot table?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You've posted what you have tried, but it might help a data example. Please, post the input and the expected output you want to get.

Comment: An easy win would be to restrain the ranges you are using. instead of B:B, use something like B2:B10000 (or whatever row number is high enough to capture all your data). Data example would help in crafting a better answer.